# Second monitor maxed at 1024 x 768

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've recently moved from Mint to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS because of a problem I encountered with my Nvidia graphics card. Happy enough, but decided to upgrade my card to an XFX R9 360.

I researched to discover that this card was supported by Ubunto and didn't need any further cabling as it was only 75 watts. I would however need a DVI-I to VGA converter, but didn't think this would be a problem.

To my horror, this wasn't the case and on top of the new (or used) card, I ended up upgrading the power supply from 350 to 650 watts to accommodate the new card. Anyway, all went well until I discovered that the Samsung 22" VGA monitor was maxed out at 1024 x 768 4.3. Also, Ubunto shows the monitor as "Unknown". The Lenovo 27" meanwhile, through HDMI is fine.

The Samsung is a widescreen monitor that had previously been running on 1080P (1920 x 1080) quite happily, yet now doesn't and there is nothing I can do to fix this.

The information out there suggests that VGA monitors won't go above 1024, which is rubbish, or that the DVI-I converter has robbed the monitor of the ability to function at max res, yet everything I have read suggests otherwise.

I would like to know whether getting a VGA to Display converter would change that or do I now need to find another monitor that is either a DVI or Display native?

Some info right now would be really helpful, but it doesn't seem as if this graphics card is fully supported as suggested.

Comment: What you describe is wrong video driver for the card.

Comment: Don't use VGA. Use DVI-D or Displayport.

Comment: In answer to Vidarlo's comment, I'm using the DVI-I output for the VGA monitor. According to sources I have checked, the DVI port should be able to output at full HD, but isn't. I don't know whether getting a Display port converter would make any difference. I can't really afford a new monitor, so I would like a way to fix the problem if possible.

Comment: In answer to David's reply, I don't think the wrong driver is being used, because that's what Ubuntu has decided on. I have tried to find native drivers without success. The one supplied by AMD doesn't install, something about dependencies. So no luck there I'm afraid.

Comment: VGA is a standard that is nearly 40 years old and its capabilities reflect that. VGA is also analog, not digital. Don't use VGA if you want to use a modern digital HD display. The capabilities of any other types of cabling are moot if you are using an adapter. Anything that converts a digital output to VGA is also being mashed through a digital to analog converter. The best performance you can ever hope to achieve is limited by the worst link in the chain and VGA is close to the bottom of the barrel.

Comment: @NickByford I'm well aware of what VGA and DVI-I is. My answer is simply that VGA is *ancient*, and has not been native for any monitor for at least 10-15 years. Don't use it. Manufacturers of monitors and cards probably doesn't test it as well as they did in it's heyday, thus issues such as what you see may occur. So in short: try with DP or DVI-D to HDMI cable.

Comment: Thanks to those of you that have answered. I have been using my Samsung VGA monitor for some time now and have never had a problem. I am currently running it through DVI-I adapter, but clearly, despite running the VGA monitor from a DVI-I port, it clearly doesn't mean I will get full HD as I did from GT710 Nvidia card's VGA socket.

I would assume that running this screen from any of the other available ports (DVI-D or Display port), the same would occur, so I am now looking for a suitable, though inexpensive (second-hand) monitor to replace the VGA monitor.

Thanks again folks!